# Битрикс - проверить существование страницы на мультиязычном сайте

Tags: php, битрикс

Необходимо проверить, есть ли версия этой страницы на другом языке на мультиязычном сайте Битрикс. У каждого из языков свой домен, но хостится все вместе (в админке Битрикс показаны обе версии).

Я знаю, что можно воспользоваться `cURL` или `file_get_contents`, но хотелось бы более элегантное (и быстрое) решение.

Answer (score 1):

## Вариант 1: использовать поиск по сайту

Текущую страницу можно получить так:

```
$page = $APPLICATION->GetCurPage(true);
```

Например, текущая страница `/index.php`.

Делаем запрос к таблице `b_search_content`:

```
SELECT LID, MODULE_ID, ITEM_ID, URL FROM `b_search_content` WHERE URL = '/index.php';

+-----+-----------+---------------+------------+
| LID | MODULE_ID | ITEM_ID       | URL        |
+-----+-----------+---------------+------------+
| en  | main      | en|/index.php | /index.php |
| on  | main      | on|/index.php | /index.php |
| it  | main      | it|/index.php | /index.php |
+-----+-----------+---------------+------------+
```

В данном случае есть три языковые версии этой страницы.

Плюсы:

- быстро
- `TITLE` возможно использовать как `<a title="...">`

Недостатки:

- не 100% результат, так как не все страницы могут быть проиндексированы
- мое решение работает, когда языки вынесены на поддомены, как будет работать для вариантов `ru/index.php`, `en/index.php` - не знаю

## Вариант 2: использовать CURL

Это решение вы сами предложили. Оно мне кажется более устойчивым. Для скорости - добавить кеширование, вплоть до "вечного" кеша.